# shorten bubble sort loop

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort

I have change my bubble sort from implementing the application traverses the entire list during each step of the sort.

This is not necessary since after the first traversal the smallest item will be at the end of the list and after the second traversal, the second smallest item will be in its correct position (2nd last) and so on. i'm a little unsure on what needs to changed exactly.

I need to modify the bubble sort so it doesn't perform unnecessary comparisons.

```js
   private void bubbleSort() {
      int currentCount = 0;
      showStatus("Sorting ...");
      boolean swap = true;
      while (swap) {
         swap = false;
         for (int i = 0; i < items.length - 1; i++) {
            if (greaterThan(items[i], items[i + 1])) {
               swapItems(items[i], items[i + 1]);
               swap = true;
               currentCount++;
            }
         } // for
      } // while
      showStatus("Sort complete, number of swaps = " + currentCount);
   } // bubbleSort   private void bubbleSort() {
```

Comment: Please remove the unnecessary code

Answer (score 0):

A bubble sort will perform unnecessary comparisons, that's why you don't use it in production for any dataset of any reasonable size.  Regarding your code in particular.  A simple look at the reference implementation on [Rosettacode](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Bubble_sort#Java)(because I don't feel like actually writing it again, you only do that in school) looks to show it doing exactly the same number of comparisons.  If you want an actually good sorting algorithm for sufficiently large N try merge-sort.

Reference

```
public static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> void bubbleSort(E[] comparable) {
    boolean changed = false;
    do {
        changed = false;
        for (int a = 0; a < comparable.length - 1; a++) {
            if (comparable[a].compareTo(comparable[a + 1]) > 0) {
                E tmp = comparable[a];
                comparable[a] = comparable[a + 1];
                comparable[a + 1] = tmp;
                changed = true;
            }
        }
    } while (changed);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, at the end of first iteration of the for loop the **biggest** element will be at the end of the array and not the smallest.

If you want to modify your code to save unneeded comparison you can check last comparison and use if as the end of the next for-loop.

Consider the following code: (I hope `java` allow while(int) - I'm not a `java` expert...)

```
integer swap = items.length - 1;
while (swap) {
    swap = 0;
    integer lastSwap = swap ;
    for (int i = 0; i < lastSwap ; i++) {
        if (greaterThan(items[i], items[i + 1])) {
           swapItems(items[i], items[i + 1]);
           swap = i;
           currentCount++;
        }
     } // for
  } // while
```